# Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in jenkins Server

Tags: java, jenkins, jmeter

I'm getting the following error while running the test with JMeter in Jenkins. Everything works perfect locally.

Do I need to add any plugins in Jenkins to fix this error?

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/Online_Search_TeeTime.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[8]/kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener
line number         : 292
version             : 5.0 r1840935
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [GraphsGeneratorListener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/) plugin